# sort a list of strings with name and number in

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of 100 filenames so they will used in the right order in later calculations. All the filenames have 'name_1' in the beginning of the name and '_out.txt' at the end. The difference is a number in between, going from 1-100

The list looks a bit like this:

`['name_1_100_out.txt', 'name_1_10_out.txt', 'name_1_6_out.txt', 'name_1_5_out.txt', 'name_1_2_out.txt']`

For this actual example I want:

`['name_1_2_out.txt', 'name_1_5_out.txt', 'name_1_6_out.txt', 'name_1_10_out.txt', 'name_1_100_out.txt']`

Now I have tried both `list.sort` and `sorted(list)` but with no luck. I have also tried with the key=int or key=str but none of them could help, since it seems, that it could not convert only a part of the string to int.

Can anyone help me with advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need leading zeros to sort the way you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

L=['name_1_100_out.txt', 'name_1_10_out.txt', 'name_1_6_out.txt', 'name_1_5_out.txt', 'name_1_2_out.txt']
OUT=[]

n='100' # max number

for item in L:
    old=item[7:-8] # Faulty index
    if len(old) < len(n):
        new='0'*(len(n)-len(old))+old # Nice index
        item=item.replace(old, new)
    OUT.append(item)

OUT.sort()

print OUT
```

Result

`['name_1_002_out.txt', 'name_1_005_out.txt', 'name_1_006_out.txt', 'name_1_010_out.txt', 'name_1_100_out.txt'`]

I would suggest renaming files to make life easier later on since not all file managers display faulty filenames in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` function for this task:

```
>>> l = ['name_1_100_out.txt', 'name_1_10_out.txt', 'name_1_6_out.txt', 'name_1_5_out.txt', 'name_1_2_out.txt']
>>> sorted(l,key=lambda s: int(s.split('_')[2]))
['name_1_2_out.txt', 'name_1_5_out.txt', 'name_1_6_out.txt', 'name_1_10_out.txt', 'name_1_100_out.txt']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lista = ['2','3','5','8','4','6','1']
listb = [('2','3'),('5','8'),('4','6'),('1','9')]
listc = {'a':'3','b':'5','c':'9','d':'4','e':'2','f':'0'}
d = sorted(lista, key=lambda item:int(item), reverse=True)
e = sorted(listb, key=lambda item:int(item[0]) + int(item[1]), reverse=True)
f = sorted(listc.items(), key=lambda item:int(item[1]), reverse=True)
print(d)
print(e)
print(f)
```

output:

```
['8', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
[('5', '8'), ('4', '6'), ('1', '9'), ('2', '3')]
[('c', '9'), ('b', '5'), ('d', '4'), ('a', '3'), ('e', '2'), ('f', '0')]
```